# Parsing and calculating numbers in R

Tags: r

Probably a simple question, but not sure how phrase / search for it...

I'm analysing my web-server logs to check the performance with R:

```
data = read.table("/path/to/log", sep=" ")
```

These logs include the URL, overall processing time, and the time certain actions took during each request (e.g. DNS lookups, which I cannot control).

For a cut down example:

```
time   path   info_extra
0.0027 /test/ -
0.0080 /test/ DNSMX=0
0.0218 /test/ DNSMX=0
0.0314 /test/ -
0.2442 /test/ DNSMX=0,PASSH=0.14
0.3962 /test/ DNSMX=0,PASSH=0.159,GEO=0.12
0.4500 /test/ DNSMX=0.018,DNSMX=0.037,PASSH=0.14,GEO=0.133
```

How can I easily split the `info_extra` values (comma separated string), and subtract the value after the equals sign, from the `time` value?

For example:

```
time   local  path   info_extra
0.0027 0.0027 /test/ -
0.0080 0.0080 /test/ DNSMX=0
0.0218 0.0218 /test/ DNSMX=0
0.0314 0.0314 /test/ -
0.2442 0.1042 /test/ DNSMX=0,PASSH=0.14
0.3962 0.1172 /test/ DNSMX=0,PASSH=0.159,GEO=0.12
0.4500 0.1220 /test/ DNSMX=0.018,DNSMX=0.037,PASSH=0.14,GEO=0.133
```

---

I might have made this a little trickier, as `info_extra` was originally extracted from an `info` field, which also stores the user and admin ID's, separated by slashes:

```
        time                                             info path  
6238  0.0027                                            0/0/- /test/
16940 0.4500 0/0/DNSMX=0.018,DNSMX=0.037,PASSH=0.14,GEO=0.133 /test/
17151 0.0314                                            0/0/- /test/
17162 0.2442                           0/0/DNSMX=0,PASSH=0.14 /test/
23112 0.3962                 0/0/DNSMX=0,PASSH=0.159,GEO=0.12 /test/
30400 0.0080                                  12035/0/DNSMX=0 /test/
39649 0.0218                                  11340/0/DNSMX=0 /test/

info = data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(data$info, "/")));
names(info) <- c("user_id", "admin_id", "info_extra");
data = cbind(data, info);
```

So I believe the `extra_info` is currently a [Factor](http://www.statmethods.net/input/datatypes.html), and this seems to upset [strsplit()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html).

---

If you're interested, the timings include:

- DNSMX: DNS check to see if an email address domain is valid.
- DNSA: Same again, but on the A record (if MX fails).
- PASSH: Hashing a password (intentionally slow, ref [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)).
- GEO: Getting the GeoCords for an address from a third party server.
- SESS: Waiting for the session lock to open.

Comment: You can add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` option in your `read.table` function call.

Comment: @danas.zuokas, thanks for the comment, but I think the factors come in from the cbind(), when I'm parsing the `info` field (the second bit), but I must admit I'm still getting my head around the different data types in R.

Comment: If you're `cbind`ing a `data.frame`, you should also be able to add `stringsAsFactors` in there.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks for the note, assuming factors should not be used (will be looking into this next), then I needed to change the data.frame method for extracting the `info` fields... for reference this is `info = data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(data$info, "/")), stringsAsFactors = FALSE);`

Comment: Well, @CraigFrancis, hopefully my answer below also addresses your question overall ;-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto Just moving onto that now, sorry for the delay last week "real" work go in the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a huge fan of pipes, but it's illustrative here of the steps I would take to address this problem.

See the comments for what's happening at each step.

```
library(dplyr)
library(splitstackshape)
# Convert to data.table, adding rownames, and making a copy
DT <- copy(setDT(mydf, keep.rownames = TRUE))

DT %>%
  cSplit("info", "/") %>%             # split "info" column by "/"
  cSplit("info_3", ",", "long") %>%   # split third output from above, long format, by ","
  cSplit("info_3", "=") %>%           # split same column again, wide format, by "="
  group_by(rn) %>%                    # group by row names   
  summarise(time = time[1],           # first value of time...
            val = sum(info_3_2)) %>%  # sum of values from "info_3_2"
  mutate(local = time - val) %>%      # calculate the difference
  left_join(mydf)                     # merge with original data
# Source: local data table [7 x 6]
# 
#      rn   time   val  local                                             info   path
#   (chr)  (dbl) (dbl)  (dbl)                                            (chr)  (chr)
# 1 16940 0.4500 0.328 0.1220 0/0/DNSMX=0.018,DNSMX=0.037,PASSH=0.14,GEO=0.133 /test/
# 2 17151 0.0314    NA     NA                                            0/0/- /test/
# 3 17162 0.2442 0.140 0.1042                           0/0/DNSMX=0,PASSH=0.14 /test/
# 4 23112 0.3962 0.279 0.1172                 0/0/DNSMX=0,PASSH=0.159,GEO=0.12 /test/
# 5 30400 0.0080 0.000 0.0080                                  12035/0/DNSMX=0 /test/
# 6 39649 0.0218 0.000 0.0218                                  11340/0/DNSMX=0 /test/
# 7  6238 0.0027    NA     NA                                            0/0/- /test/
```

---

Here's the sample data used in this answer:

```
mydf <- structure(list(time = c(0.0027, 0.45, 0.0314, 0.2442, 0.3962, 
    0.008, 0.0218), info = c("0/0/-", "0/0/DNSMX=0.018,DNSMX=0.037,PASSH=0.14,GEO=0.133", 
    "0/0/-", "0/0/DNSMX=0,PASSH=0.14", "0/0/DNSMX=0,PASSH=0.159,GEO=0.12", 
    "12035/0/DNSMX=0", "11340/0/DNSMX=0"), path = c("/test/", "/test/", 
    "/test/", "/test/", "/test/", "/test/", "/test/")), .Names = c("time", 
    "info", "path"), row.names = c("6238", "16940", "17151", "17162", 
    "23112", "30400", "39649"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a variable where you have `sum(info_3_2)`? annoyingly some logs don't follow exactly the same format ... And where you have the line `DT %>%` I've changed that to `mydf <- DT %>%`, so I can work with the result, but it's now a DataTable. Is it possible to use `setDF` with `rownames` to convert it back to a DataFrame? `setDF(mydf, rownames="rn");`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(data)

tmp <- dt[, tstrsplit(info, '/')]
tmp <- tmp[, tstrsplit(V3, ',')]
out <- tmp[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, '='), function(y) as.numeric(y[2]))))]
```

First `lapply` takes each column of a `data.table`. Second `lapply` is for taking value in a second position (`strsplit` returns a list). Then subtraction is straightforward `dt[, time - out]`.

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion, I can see where it's going, and I like how it only uses the data.table package (one I was already using), but it looks like Ananda's solution takes it to completion... for reference it was the last step `dt[, time - out]`, which was taking each of the info values and subtracting them from the overall request time, whereas I was hoping to sum those together, and apply it back to the main `data` DataFrame (so I could see the time spent not doing the listed things)... but thanks again (was also good to learn about tstrsplit).